# In my wordpress admin panel Suddenly The Category, tag and featured Image Option are not showing

Tags: categories, post-thumbnails, tags

In my wordpress admin panel Suddenly The Category, tag and featured Image Option are not showing. I write blogs in my wordpress blogs but suddenly there are missing three options for adding The Category, tag and featured Image. What to do now ?[image: The Category, tag and featured Image]

Comment: Check for plugin conflicts by disabling plugins and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. First question, did you add any plugins recently? If so disable them and see if the issue remains.
2. Second question, did you update any plugins lately and/or theme files?
3. Third question, did you add any custom programming to the site recently, if so remove it temporarily and test.
4. Fourth question, did you change any settings in plugins or theme files lately? If so reverse them and check

Always check the most recent to a site when something like this happens.

Also: Check Screen Options: At the top right of the post editing screen in the WordPress admin panel, there's a "Screen Options" dropdown. Click on it and ensure that the checkboxes for Categories, Tags, and Featured Image are ticked. If they are unchecked, these options won't be displayed on the screen.